# Cómo insertar datos en un arreglo cada que se necesite en c++

Tags: c++, array, funciones

Se pide ingresar los datos del paciente cada vez que se seleccione la opción 1. Hay tres opciones uno para entradas de datos uno por uno, otro para la salida de datos en conjunto y por ultimo un botón de salir.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

string datos[4];
int opcion;
void menu();
void opcion1();
void opcion2();
void asignacion();

void menu(){

    cout<<"\tAdministracion de Voluntarios al Ensayo de la T-vacuna"<<endl;
    cout<<"\n1 Procedimiento de asignar solucion inyectable"<<endl;
    cout<<"2 Listado de participantes"<<endl;
    cout<<"3 Salir"<<endl;
    cout<<"Ingresa la opcion: ";
    cin>>opcion;

    switch(opcion){
        case 1: opcion1();
                break;
        case 2: opcion2();
                break;
        case 3: system("cls");
         cout<<"saliste";//falta boton salir
    }
}

void opcion1(){1
cout<<"Bienvenido Voluntario Nro 1"<<endl;
```

En esta parte puede lograr llenar el arreglo pero solo se puede todos al mismo tiempo quisiera que el arreglo se llene cada vez que entren a esta opción:

```
for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
cout<<"Ingresar nombre y apellidos:";
cin>>datos[i];
}
cout<<"Se le administrara placebo"<<endl;
menu();
}

void opcion2(){
cout<<"Listado de participantes:"<<endl;
cout<<"Nro"<<"  "<<"Nombre"<<"          "<<"Vacuna"<<"  "<<"Placebo"<<endl;
for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
    
    cout<<"\n"<<i<<"    "<<datos[i];
    
}
getch();//hfdgdss
menu(); //fsdfsff
}

int main(){
menu();//asdas
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas una variable que te diga cuántos elementos hay en el array en un momento dado. Dado que esta variable está íntimamente relacionada con el array, lo suyo es que vayan juntas todo el rato

```
constexpr int MAX_ELEMENTOS = 4;
struct Listado
{
    string datos[MAX_ELEMENTOS];
    int num_elementos = 0;
};
```

Así, para añadir un elemento:

```
void nuevo(Listado & listado)
{
    if (listado.num_elementos < MAX_ELEMENTOS)
    {
        int & index = listado.num_elementos;
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, listado.datos[index];
        index++;
    }
}
```

Ahora te queda reemplazar el array de tu programa por una instancia de la estructura:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
---------
Listado datos;
int opcion;
void menu();
void opcion1();
void opcion2();
void asignacion();
```

Y actualizar los usos de tu antiguo array

Comment: ese tema es estructura de datos? o como lo podrai buscar en youtube?